# Replica set architecture - Arbiter requirement

Tags: mongodb, replicaset, mongodb-replica-set, database

What should be the number of replica set members required to handle Disaster Recovery ( DR ) situation effectively.Currently we are using 3 node replica set ( 1 primary , 1 secondary in same region and 1 secondary in DR region ).
We are planning to add 2 arbiters to it to increase its   fault tolerance.
Is it a good practice to use more than one arbiter instance ?
Would it be better to create the arbiter instance in DR zone ?

Answer (score 1):

As JJussi points out, adding more than one arbiter will not help at all, but it might be useful to add further nodes (data-bearing and/or arbiter) to achieve maximum resilience and availability.

Your current arrangement is like this:

[image: Existing replicaset configuration]

If your datacentre in region 1 goes down, then the node in the DR region won't be able to step up to primary, because it could not command a majority:

[image: DR region cannot provide high availability]

Even if you added a further data-bearing node and an arbiter, you would run into the same problem if they were in the same two regions.

Instead, what I recommend you configure is your existing two nodes in region 1, add a fourth data-bearing node to the DR region, but also add an arbiter but make sure the arbiter is in a different region again:

[image: 5-node replicaset configuration with high-availability]

That way, even if the datacentre goes down in region 1 or the DR region, the nodes in the other region will be able to — with the help of the arbiter —
 command a majority, and continue working:

[image: Continued operation despite the loss of an entire data-centre]

Answer (score 0):

Arbiters don't increase fault tolerance, because they don't hold data. You don't have any need to add arbiters to the current setup, because you already have an odd count of votes. You current node count (three) is perfect for DR, especially if all three nodes are in different data centers, even two of those are in same geographical region.

Of course you can always add one node (and then you need arbiter) to some other region, but normally three separated nodes is perfect DR situation. If all your current nodes are in USA, you could have "half" (enough to majority) of nodes located to Europe...